# Can I control plugin load order from outside a plugin in Grails?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I would like to control plugin load order from outside of a plugin in Grails.

From within a plugin you can control load order with dependsOn, loadAfter or loadBefore:
http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/plugins.html#understandingPluginLoadOrder

But is it possible to do this from outside of the plugin?  I don't want to modify the original plugin.

My end goal is to use the database-migration plugin to manage the quartz plugin and activiti plugin database schemas.

Comment: This question is similar to, but not quite the same as another unanswered question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448440/specifying-order-of-plugins-in-grails

Comment: I won't add this as an answer because it does not address the original question, but rather my end goal.  Even if you modify the original plugins to "loadAfter" the dbm plugin, it still fails because the migration doesn't actually occur until late in the application startup process.  The migration runs after the spring app context is fully instantiated (via the dbm plugin's doWithApplicationContext block), whereas the activiti plugin is already accessing the database by that point( having started access in a constructor in doWithSpring).  So this question is a little less immediately useful.

Comment: Anyone know if this is possible? Basically control load order of third party plugins from BuildConfig.groovy?

Comment: I wasn't able to find a solution to this question, and ended up working around it.

Comment: Thanks. It's a shame you can only specify within the plugin as it's hard for plugin developers to be be aware of all possible dependencies.